# How to add black and white effect to window manager?

Tags: android

With the code bellow , I can attach a colorful view as an effect to window manager:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        view.getBackground().setAlpha(70);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        WindowManager manager2 = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        manager2.addView(view, params);
```

Now, I want to make a black and white effect for window manager. I mean I want to make all of the device screen black and white!

How can I add Such an effect to window manager?